# Bootstrap dropdown won't work when included using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap:

Why won't a dropdown work when included using JQuery but does work when I copy and paste?

This is the code I have:

```
....
    <!--import Navigation bar html -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $("#includedContent").load("navBar.html"); 
        });
    </script>  
    <!--end Navigation bar html -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--import Navigation bar html -->
        <div id="includedContent"></div>
        <!-- /#pageWrapper location -->
....
```

Comment: copy/paste what exactly?

Comment: Show us a example of what's not working and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: its bootstrap so its hard to copy and past the entire 1500 lines of code (and im not sure how relevant it would be either?)  
  
- Basically i have a 300 lines of html for a navBar that appears in multiple .html files. If i wanted to change an aspect of the navBar i would have to manually update every instance of it in each file. to rectify this i moved the navBar html code to its own .html file and then (using the above Jquery code) i imported it to the <body> tag where needed. Now i only have to update the single navBar code.  Have i gone about this the right way? or is there a better way?